# Glowing material with variable glow in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am new to ThreeJS library. I am making an electrical circuit and would like to vary the brightness of the bulb according to the current flow. Is there any material in the ThreeJS library whose brightness can be varied? I used MeshLambertMaterial and tried to vary its shininess but it didn't work out. Can someone give me some example of it being done? Can I somehow vary the brightness by varying the color of the material?

Comment: Yes - there are many ways to do this. The most direct I can think of is simply to link the color of the material to your current flow value, or choose among the lights in the api. What code do you have so far? Post a link to a fiddle/codepen or a code snippet from what you already have.

Comment: I have to submit the code in a competition somewhere so I can't share it here. If someone copies it then I would get disqualified. How can the color be linked to brightness?

Comment: Make the color lighter by increasing each of the RGB values (relative to your flow value) - that can simulate a brightening.